# How to compile x264 for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, x264

I'm trying to compile x264 for use in an iPhone application. I can compile with using http://github.com/gabriel/ffmpeg-iphone-build File: build-x264-armv6/7.
but only decoding. I want to use encoding too.
when I use build-x264-armv6/7,The console show me "mp4 output: no".

Does anyone know how to compile x264 which is able to encoding H.264?

Comment: Be aware that x264 is under the GPL license, meaning that you will need to make the source code to any application using it available under the GPL license as well.  Additionally, the GPL license may not be compatible with the App Store distribution method.

Comment: Hello Brad Larson, Thank you for your advice.
well, please tell me which codec that is able to play on MPMoviePlayerController would be nice.

Comment: x264 is a encoder not a decoder.